# Can't update java.security file - want to add bouncy castle provider

Tags: java

I am trying to use 'Bouncy castle' library in JAVA and want to add that jar file(bouncy castle's) to the providers list in the 'java.security file', I'm using windows7 and I have changed the permissions too for the files and folders but yet I'm getting an error **"Access to 'complete-path' was denied"**. Kindly help me in how to deal with this error.

Comment: Have you tried the security policy tool ? if not try it by executing this command in your cmd >> policytool

Comment: Have you checked whether you have permission for usage for the given user for the parent and ancestor folders?

Comment: What program are you using to edit the java.security file?  Try running that editor as administrator. (Don't use Notepad; Notepad only supports CR+LF line endings but java.security files use LF line endings.)

Comment: @JUBA can you please explain a bit more? how to check this?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes i rechecked again , but still having same problem..

Comment: @LukeWoodward i tried with Dreamweaver, does it really matter? :/

Comment: @Mehdia: I don't know Dreamweaver so I don't know whether it would work.  I normally use Notepad++ for this.

Comment: @LukeWoodward now in Notepad++ it says "Please Check if this file is opened in another program", though it's not!

Comment: @Mehdia: have you run Notepad++ as administrator?  If it's already running, quit it first.

Comment: @Mehdia, There is a GUI tool for adding permissions, try it and you will find all kinds of permissions you want, and i realy don't know what kinds of permissions DreamWeaver needs, so i guess you have to try permisstions in the tool your self.

Comment: @JUBA thanks for your concern dear, by following Lukewood's instruction(through Notepad++) it's done now :)

Comment: Glad my instructions helped you.  I've now added an answer that summarises my comments, in the hope that the next person who comes across this question finds it helpful.

Comment: That's so sweet of you, thank you so much @LukeWoodward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only save edits made to a `java.security` file if the editor you are using is running as an administrator.

Notepad is sadly not good enough for this job, as Notepad only supports files with CR+LF line-endings and `java.security` uses LF line endings.  I normally use Notepad++ for this task, although Notepad2 and various other programmer's editors can be used instead if that's your preference.

Note that you must quit Notepad++ if it is currently running.  If Notepad++ is running and you attempt to start another copy of it (as administrator or otherwise), Notepad++ will figure out that it is already running and instead give focus to the already-running copy of Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to copy the file somewhere else, update it and paste it back in. There is a security warning that I had to say 'continue' to.